# Oracle sys_refcursor from normal SQL

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, plsql, sys-refcursor

I have a (simplified) Oracle SQL like this:

```
declare
  xd number;
  xm number;
  DataOut sys_refcursor;
begin
  xd := to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'dd'));
  xm := to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'mm'));

  open DataOut for
  select * from dual;  
end;
```

And I want to be able to fill a DataTable in .Net from the data returned in the DataOut parameter.

I have been trying various things but can't seem to access the DataOut cursor.
How would I call this?

```
OracleCommand c = new OracleCommand();
c.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
c.CommandText = SQL;

OracleParameter param = new OracleParameter();
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
param.OracleType = OracleType.Cursor;
param.ParameterName = "DataOut";
c.Parameters.Add(param);

c.Connection = (OracleConnection) this.GetConnection();

OracleString rowNum = "";
c.ExecuteOracleNonQuery(out rowNum);
// or c.ExecuteReader()
// or use OracleDataAdapter

DataTable returnTable = /* magic goes here */
```

I can edit the SQL but I'm not able to create functions or procedures.
Is this possible?

Comment: Have you simplified your example too much? You know that PL/SQL block doesn't return anything right?

Comment: Well I'm not a Oracle guy but my client sent this sample to me and told me I should be able to get the data from the DataOut variable.

Comment: Can I maybe change it to a return value? How would I do that? Thanks :) I'm really lost here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An anonymous PL/SQL block does not return anything so you won't be able to use the cursor you open in the anonymous PL/SQL block in your client application.  In order to return the data to the client application, you would need to use a named PL/SQL block (i.e. a stored procedure or a stored function).  If you are not allowed to create named PL/SQL blocks, you won't be able to return a cursor you open in PL/SQL to your client application.

Comment: Great thanks. But could I solve this problem somehow, is there a way to get something from a sys_refcursor to .Net without named procedures. For example by selecting from it?

Comment: @GunnarSteinn - No.  A `sys_refcursor` is PL/SQL construct, not a SQL construct.  It can only be declared in a PL/SQL block.  And it can only be returned to the caller if the PL/SQL block returns something which is only possible with named PL/SQL blocks that can declare parameters and returns.  You could, of course, construct whatever SQL statement you would construct in the PL/SQL block in your .Net application and just execute that SQL statement from .Net, bypassing the need for PL/SQL entirely.

Answer (score 0):

```
select cursor(select * from dual) from dual;
```